# Shell written in C has Output Redirection Error: segmentation fault

Tags: c, shell, unix, file-descriptor

I'm trying to complete my output redirection function for a C shell assignment. However, when entering a command such as: echo hello world > test.txt my shell exits with a segmentation fault that I suspect to be the line: args[i] = strtok(NULL," ") I don't believe I am NULL terminating the argument array correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "execute.h"
#include "parser.h"

#define ReadFd 0
#define WriteFd 1

void outred(char ** args, char * filename, int pos){

   pid_t pid;
  int fd[2];//array of two for each file descriptor

  int buffer_size = BUFFSIZE;
  int status;

  //only want tokens before the ">" metacharacter
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < pos; i++;){
    args[i] = args[i];
  }
  args[i] = strtok(NULL," ");

pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0){//If in child process execute the cmd to write to the file

 close(fd[ReadFd]);//child recieves fds from parent
 fd[WriteFd] = creat(filename, 0644);//create file

 dup2(fd[WriteFd],fileno(stdout));//duplicate write end to stdout, output to stdout goes to write end instead

 close(fd[WriteFd]);//new execution will write to stdout which is being redirected to fd[WriteFd] so it can be closed

    execvp(args[0],args);//execute cmd on args

  }

  if(pid < 0){
    perror("ERROR: output redirect failed");//no execution 
    exit(0);
    }

  if(pid > 0){
    close(fd[WriteFd]);    
    wait(&status);

  }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't have much in the way of error checking or handling, so where's that error message coming from? (Also, compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang) if you're not already doing so).

Comment: The section 
  `int i;
  for(i = 0; i < pos; i++;){
    args[i] = args[i];
  }` is odd.  The comment before isn't justified by the code on display.  You've not provided an MCVE ([MCVE]) so we can't see what you're doing in the calling code.  All of which makes it hard to know what to think of the code, and we can't do much in the way of consulting the compiler because there's so much missing.

Comment: It isn't clear what the `fd` array is doing; it isn't initialized, so it is extremely dubious.  It isn't obvious how that causes the crash you claim to see, but it isn't well defined behaviour.

Comment: This is closely related to a previous question by the same OP, namely [I/O redirection in shell written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572028/i-o-redirection-in-shell-written-in-c).  I'm not sure it isn't a duplicate,

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT:  regarding: `exit(0);`  normally returned 0 indicates success, but this is a failure exit.  Suggest using `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`